# How to hide object filenames in a static library?

Tags: c, xcode, gcc, obfuscation

I want to deliver a C static library  and hide the internal implementation as much as possible. I am using a code obfuscator on my code and that works very well for making symbols incomprhensible for a human. I am using xcode 4 which I assume has GCC like flags.

My problem is that my library still contains readable informations that I would like to hide or make incomprehensible to human:

1- Object file names: 
     When I run nm on the .a , I still see the names of each object file. (i.e myObect1.o myObject2.o etc). Is there a way to remove these names from my .a?

2- file paths:
  When I run strings on my library, I still see paths to headers files as well as some .c file paths (included as #include). Is there a way to remove these as well. (GCC flag or other way)?

Thanks for you help,

baba

ps: I know about nm and strings but if you know of any other tools or if you can suggest anything else I should check is properly hidden in my .a, all suggestion is welcome.

Comment: See if [GNU strip](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strip) can do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider distributing an amalgamation as SQLite does: http://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html. In other words, instead of a library, distribute a single .o file and a single .h file.

You'll have to annotate your internal functions as static. This will also give the compiler further opportunity for optimization. Lua uses such annotations. See for instance http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/ldo.h.html. For an amalgamation, `LUAI_FUNC` is defined as static.

Comment: Thanks it works! One question though: What is the benefit of declaring internal functions as static (their names are already obfuscated and thus non human readable). Also can declaring functions as static induce any problems like for instance on embedded plateforms like ios? I am just not so familiar with the use of the static keyword and I have heard of limitations of declaring variables as static on embedded platforms. Would it be the same for functions?

Comment: @Baba, like I said, static functions allows the compiler to generate better code, even inlining them. Static functions are not really the same as static variables. They only share the fact that they're not visible outside the module. No, static functions should not give any problems in embedded platforms.